# div filling parent and center children

Tags: html, css, css-position

With a pretty simple markup I need to :

- Extends a div to fill it's parent height
- Center the children of that element vertically

So the `#wrapper` must take all possible height, pushing the footer to the bottom of `#container`. the divs inside must keep their side, so it's only their position that will change. (basically only the elements position will evolve, not their size).

Also I need a compatibility with ie8 (so no flexbox sadly).

The only fixed size that exists is the one of the `#container`.

Here is the snippet :

```css
/* position */
/* any idea ? */

/* fixed size */
#container { height: 300px; }

/* display purpose */
* {
  border: 1px black solid;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #fff;
}
#container { background-color: #999; }
#header, #wrapper { background-color: #666; }
#footer, #list { background-color: #444; }
#list div { background-color: #222; }
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="list">
      <div>div</div>
      <div>div</div>
      <div>div</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">footer</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I looked at table display, absolute positioning, `:before` hack, but nothing get this right...

Here is a codepen with the same code : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NPPVZX

The result should look like this : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPPeOv

(but with the possibility of more/less div in the list and different footer/header size)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
/* position */
#wrapper, #list, #list div { flex-grow: 1; }

/* fixed size */
#container { height: 300px; }

/* display purpose */
div{
  border : 1px black solid;
  margin: 2px;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#container        { background-color : #999; }
#header, #wrapper { background-color : #666; }
#footer, #list    { background-color : #444; }
#list div         { background-color : #222; }
```

forked http://codepen.io/Logo/pen/KwwjWr

Not sure if this is what you want.

**EDIT** Sorry.

```
/* position */
#wrapper { height: 91%; }
#list { height: 90%; }
#list div { margin-bottom: 9.9%; }
```

This uses the percentage, which I'm not sure whether ie8 supports or not, and that what you mean by "divs inside must keep their side", so I assume you want the height to be untouched for `#list div`s.

If that is not your case, then go with

```
#list div { height: 31.5%; }
```

**EDT 2**
This is another try.

Try 1

```
/* position */
#container *, #wrapper * { max-height: 90.5%; }
#list { padding:9.6% 0; }
```

This isn't a fully automated attempt, such that you have to change the padding or the height in case they are differed.

Try 2: Use many tables.

Short answer [here](http://codepen.io/Logo/pen/KwwjWr?editors=110), but since I added too much things, such as remodifying the layout (adding a layer of div for nesting tables), and a lot of `display:table`s, the layout is a bit broken (such that the margins are uneven). This is the most I can do.

Comment: Not really, I wasn't clear enough, I update my question. Thanks though!

Comment: Updated. Is this what you want now?

Comment: In that case, I afraid I can't help you anymore. There are only 3 ways to do it, 1 is to manually calculate the widths each time, 2 is to use Javascript to automate the process, 3 is stop hacking for ie8s.

Comment: Added something hopefully can help. It is not as aligned but it works flexibly as you wish

Answer (score 0):

An answer with a little more markup, thanks to @logo, here is a codepen with the desired effect : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEPNby

```
/* position */

#header { display:table-header-group; }
#footer { display:table-footer-group; }
#wrapper2 { height:100%; }
#wrapper, #list { display:table-cell; }
#container, #wrapper2 { display:table; width: 100%;}
#list { vertical-align: middle; }
```

Thanks again !